# Why operations over Path realized in form of static methods?

Tags: java, file, coding-style, java-7

IMHO, `path.delete()` looks a little better than `Files.delete(path)`. But developers of `java.nio.file` package preferred to realize operations over `Path` in form of `Paths`'s static methods. Why?

Answer (score 1):

It are utilitiy implementations, a design pattern as in Collection/Collections, File/Files, Path/Paths. Paths can handle different (virtual) "file" systems, like a zip file system. Hence a Path is associated with a file system, and a `delete` would delegate nevertheless to the file system delete. For instance:

For a zip file system view can have File path `c:\data\x\y` zip path relative `x/y`. You can move/rename/copy between paths. Having file operations reside in Path would be pure delegating calls.

They chose to let Path be a pure data structure even more than File, a bit like URL.

So there is some *code design* justification. But agreed, having several ~s classes, maybe used intermixed (Path+File+Paths+Files), does not make for a clean *API style design*.

Answer (score 0):

Because, as the Javadoc states, a [`Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) is

> An object that may be used to locate a file in a file system. It will
>   typically represent a system dependent file path.

It's not actually a file, it just describes the path to the file. So there's nothing to delete or rather deleting doesn't make sense on a path. It only makes sense on a file.

Comment: Then my question is, why to have such weak path abstraction instead of actually-file abstraction?

Comment: @Lescott I would have to say _separation of concerns_. But you'd have to ask the designers of the language for a complete answer.